# Captcha not showing on Data Explorer

Tags: bug, data-explorer, captcha, ssl

I was trying to execute a query on data.stackexchange.com, since I wasn't logged in I get  asked to solve the captcha (Which is fine).  However data.stackexchange.com  is failing to display the captcha for me and presents this error:

[image]

Comment: HTTPS is not fully supported, try http://data.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @Stijn - brilliant. That solved it, thanks :)